# Why sqlpackage publish action takes 30 minutes?

Tags: sql-server, sqlpackage

I'm running `sqlpackage` publish action for one `predeploy` file with one `alter` command against my `prod sql server` and it takes about 30 minutes! What is the reason for it? I see it creates complex `select` statement for `[sys] tables`. Is it mandatory or we can avoid it somehow using these flags:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-publish?view=sql-server-ver15#parameters-for-the-publish-action